# How to reset a IXAudio2SourceVoice's 'SamplesPlayed' counter after flushing source buffers?

Tags: xaudio2

[`IXAudio2SourceVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nn-xaudio2-ixaudio2sourcevoice) has a [`GetState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2sourcevoice-getstate) function which returns an [`XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/ns-xaudio2-xaudio2_voice_state) structure. This structure has a `SamplesPlayed` member, which is:

> Total number of samples processed by this voice since it last started, or since the last audio stream ended (as marked with the XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM flag).

What I want to be able to do it stop the source voice, flush all its buffers, and then reset the `SamplesPlayed` counter to zero. Neither calling [`Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2sourcevoice-stop) nor [`FlushSourceBuffers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2sourcevoice-flushsourcebuffers) will by themselves reset `SamplesPlayed`. And while flagging the last buffer with `XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM` *does* correctly reset `SamplesPlayed` back to zero, this seemingly *only* works if that last buffer is played to completion; if the buffer is flushed, then `SamplesPlayed` does *not* get reset. I have also tried calling [`Discontinuity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/xaudio2/nf-xaudio2-ixaudio2sourcevoice-discontinuity) both before and after stopping/flushing with no effect.

My current workaround is, after stopping and flushing the source voice, to submit a tiny 1-sample silent buffer with the `XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM` flag set and then let the source voice play to process that buffer and thus reset `SamplesPlayed` to zero. This works fine-ish for my use case, but it seems pretty hacky/clumsy. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Which version of XAudio2 are you using?

Comment: Right now my code auto selects the latest available version out of 2.7, 2.8, and 2.9.

Comment: Avoid that pain. Just use [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist).

Comment: Steam doesn't have an automatic installer for the XAudio2 redistributable, which makes using it the much more painful option. (And the above problem occurs regardless of which version of XAudio2 I'm using.)

Comment: The XAudio2Redist doesn't need any installer. You just drop the ``xaudio2redist.dll`` into your application directory. BTW, you ideally avoid all 'legacy DirectX SDK' things so there's no need to rely on Steam's installer. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, thanks for pointing it out! And great blog post, super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the XAudio2 source, there's no exposed way to do that in the API other than letting a packet play with `XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM`.

Calling `Discontinuity` sets up the end-of-stream flag on the currently playing buffer, or if there's none playing and a queued buffer it sets it there. You need to call `Discontinuity` and then let the voice play to completion before you recycle it.